# Two questions about the initial value theorem for pdfs

Tags: probability-theory, laplace-transform, density-function, initial-value-problems

Let $f$ be a probability density function (pdf) of a non-negative random variable. Let the Laplace transform of $f$ be defined as
\begin{align}
\phi(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} f(x)\, dx. 
\end{align}

The [initial value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20the%20initial,known%20under%20the%20abbreviation%20IVT.)  states that
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} t \phi(t)=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x).
\end{align}

I have the following questions about this result

1. What is the minimal condition on $f$ such that this identity holds? For example, will it hold if we only impose $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)<\infty$? Note that one sufficient condition is that $f$ is bounded, which follows from the dominated convergence theorem.
2. What happens if $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)=\infty$? Does $\lim_{t \to \infty} t \phi(t)=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)=\infty$? Or, do we have an example where $\lim_{t \to \infty} t \phi(t)<\infty$?

**Here is the proof of IVT**

We use the assumption that $f$ is bounded.

\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} t \phi(t)
&=\lim_{t \to \infty} t \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} f(x) \,dx \\
&=\lim_{t \to \infty}  \int_0^\infty e^{-x} f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \lim_{t \to \infty}  f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) dx \quad \text{ using DCT and assumption $f$ is bounded}\\
&=  f(0^{+}) \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \lim_{t \to \infty}   dx  \\
&=  f(0^{+}) 
\end{align}